# Particularity of Galois-Extensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois-Extension and $G=Aut_K(L)$ its Galois-Group.

My book ("Algebra" by Siegfried Bosch) states that, "An important property of Galois-Extensions $L/K$ is manifested in the fact that $K$ is the fixed field of the Galois-Group $G$. This means, that $K$  consists of all elements of $L$ which are fixed under all elements of $G$."

Now, I don't understand what is so special about this. A $K$-Automorphism is defined to be an extension of the identity map of $K$. So I of course expect $K$ to be the fixed field.

I can only imagine that there are no other elements fixed under $G$, because otherwise it would not make sense.

Comment: There are no additional elements fixed by $G$

Comment: So, this is it? Is this only true if the Galois-Group $G$ is finite?

Comment: The fact $K = L^G$ for some finite group $G \subset Aut(L)$ means we can find the minimal polynomial (over $K$) of any element $\alpha \in L$ with $$f(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G(\alpha)} (x-\beta) \in L^G[x] = K[x]$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can only imagine that there are no other elements fixed under G, because otherwise it would not make sense.

Yes, exactly: the field fixed by $G$ will be bigger if the extension is not Galois.  For instance, let $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and consider the non-Galois extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$.  Then $G = \operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{Q}(L) = \{\operatorname{id}\}$, so the fixed field of $G$ is all of $L$.

The problem is that the other roots of $x^3-2$ do not lie in $L$, so there is no place to send $\sqrt[3]{2}$ (except to itself).  This hints at the equivalence of two definitions of *Galois* for finite extensions:

- the fixed field of $\operatorname{Aut}_K(L)$ is exactly $K$; and
- $L$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial.